# Fetch helm overridded values after installation is done

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I have done an helm installation using following command and installation is completed.

```
helm  install  <micro-service-helm-chart> --set parm1=foo,parm2=bar
```

In the helm chart `parm1` was set to `a` and `parb2` was set to `b`, Now I have overrided these values from command line during helm install to `foo` and `bar` respectively.

Now, is there a way to check the value of `parm1` and `parm2` using `helm` or `kubectl` command ?
I already tried:

```
helm  ls --debug
helm  status
kubectl describe pod <podname>
```

Comment: can you check with `helm show values <chart-name>` ?

Comment: `show` --> `get`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 helm get values —all RELEASE_NAME
```

where you should fill in your release‘s name to identify the installation.